# This Object In javascript is not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried but i cant seem to delete the list when the cross button is clicked. Can Anybody explain why 'this' is not working here ?
Or there is some other way to know which cross button was clicked other than using 'this' object ?

```js
$(function(){
 $("#btn").on("click",function(){
 var text = $("#input").val();
 if(text==""){
  alert("please enter a task!");
 }
 else{
 var task = $("<li></li>").text(text);
 $(task).append("<button class= 'rem'>X</button>");
 $("#ordered").append(task);
 }
});
 $(".rem").on("click",function(){
  $(this).hide(1000);
 });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
 <title>Javascript Addition</title>
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
 
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>My To-Do List </h1>
  <input id = "input" placeholder ="Add your task Here...">
  <button id = "btn">clickkk</button>
  <ol id = "ordered">
   </ol>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="todo.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">
        <head>
            <title>Javascript Addition</title>
            <meta charset = "utf-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>My To-Do List </h1>
            <input id = "input" placeholder ="Add your task Here...">
            <button id = "btn">clickkk</button>
            <ol id = "ordered"></ol>

      </body>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="todo.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btn").on("click", function() {
            var text = $("#input").val();
            if (text == "") {
                alert("please enter a task!");
            } else {
                $("#input").val("");
                var task = $("<li></li>").text(text);
                $(task).append("<button class='rem'>X</button>");
                $("#ordered").append(task);
            }
        });

        $("body").delegate( '.rem', "click", function() {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
      </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can hide the button. Instead of `$(".rem").on("click",function(){`, you can use `$("body").on("click", '.rem', function() {`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btn").on("click", function() {
    var text = $("#input").val();
    if (text == "") {
      alert("please enter a task!");
    } else {
      var task = $("<li></li>").text(text);
      $(task).append("<button class='rem'>X</button>");
      $("#ordered").append(task);
    }
  });
});

$("body").on("click", '.rem', function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>My To-Do List </h1>
<input id="input" placeholder="Add your task Here...">
<button id="btn">clickkk</button>
<ol id="ordered">
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). since you are adding li dynamically. To remove you need to find nearest li and hide it.

```js
$(function(){
 $("#btn").on("click",function(){
 var text = $("#input").val();
 if(text==""){
  alert("please enter a task!");
 }
 else{
 var task = $("<li></li>").text(text);
 $(task).append("<button class= 'rem'>X</button>");
 $("#ordered").append(task);
 }
});
 $(document).on("click",'.rem',function(){ 
       $(this).closest('li').hide();
 });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
 <title>Javascript Addition</title>
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
 
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>My To-Do List </h1>
  <input id = "input" placeholder ="Add your task Here...">
  <button id = "btn">clickkk</button>
  <ol id = "ordered">
   </ol>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="todo.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```